# Angle between of a sum of unit vectors on a plane

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry

Assume we have N unit vectors $a_1, \dots, a_N$ on a plane. Let $\arg a_i$ be an angle between x axis and vector $a_i$ (vectors $a_i$ can be treated as complex numbers). Is it true that $$\arg \sum_{i=1}^N a_i = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^N\arg a_i}{N}$$
For the case when N=2 the equality is correct (just draw a parallelogram). Intuitively the equality is correct for arbitrary N due to symmetry, but how to prove?

EDIT: assume that all $\arg a_i \in (0, \pi)$, so sum of vectors $a_i$ cannot result in zero vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it work? I tried $[0,1], [1,0], [1, 2]/\sqrt{5}$ and did not get the answer you seek.